# C++ zilib deflate/inflate and ztream parameters

Tags: c++, compression, zlib, inflate, deflate

After understood (with some help...) how work the compress and uncompress functions of zlib library, I'm now trying to understand how deflate and inflate work. As far as i understand, compress is used in a single call, whereas deflate can be called several time.

Having a simple program with a Particle struct (coordinate x, y, z), I can deflate my datas without errors (getting a Z_STREAM_END response) and then inflate them with another z_stream object (Z_STREAM_END response too). But when I tried to display back my datas from the inflate response, I can get the x and y coordinate of my struct by not the third one (z).

I think it's due to a wrong parameters i gave to my z_stream object for inflate, but I can't find which one. As far as i understand reading docs and example, that's how I think z_stream works (this is just an example) :

```
// Here i give a total memory size for the output buffer used by deflate func
#define CHUNK 16384

struct Particle
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

...

// An element to get a single particule and give it to deflate func
Bytef *dataOriginal = (Bytef*)malloc( sizeof(Particle) );

// This var will be used to pass compressed data
Bytef *dataCompressed = (Bytef*)malloc( CHUNK );

z_stream strm;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
deflateInit(&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
strm.next_out = dataCompressed;

int nbrLoop = 2;
int spaceUsed = 0;
int flush;
Particle p;

for (var i = 0; i<nbrLoop; i++){
    // set all values equals to 0
    memset( &p, 0, sizeof(Particle) );

    // insert some random values
    p.x = (i+1) * 1;
    p.y = (i+1) * 3;
    p.z = (i+1) * 7;

    //copy this values in a Bytef* elements
    memcpy( dataOriginal, &p, sizeof(Particle) );


    strm.avail_in = sizeof(dataOriginal);
    strm.next_in = dataOriginal;

    // If it's the last particle :
    if(i == nbrLoop - 1){
    flush = Z_FINISH;
    }
    else{
        flush = Z_NO_FLUSH;
    }

    int response = deflate(&strm, flush);

    // I don't get any errors here
    // EDIT : Get Z_OK at first loop, the Z_STREAM_END at second (last)
    if( res == Z_STREAM_END ){
        spaceUsed = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
    }
}

deflateEnd(&strm);

// Trying to get back my datas
Bytef *decomp = (Bytef*)malloc( sizeof(Particle) );

z_stream strmInflate;
strmInflate.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strmInflate.zfree = Z_NULL;
strmInflate.opaque = Z_NULL;
inflateInit(&strmInflate);

// datas i want to get at the next inflate
strmInflate.avail_in = sizeof(Particle);
strmInflate.next_in = dataCompressed;

// Two particles were compressed, so i need to get back two
strmInflate.avail_out = sizeof(Particle) * 2;
strmInflate.next_out = decomp;

int response = inflate( &strmInflate, Z_NO_FLUSH );
// No error here,
// EDIT : Get Z_OK

inflateEnd( &strmInflate );

Particle testP;
memset( &testP, 0, sizeof(Particle) );
memcpy( &testP, decomp, sizeof(Particle) );

std::cout << testP.x << std::endl; // display 1 OK
std::cout << testP.y << std::endl; // display 3 OK
std::cout << testP.z << std::endl; // display 0 NOT OK
```

Moreover, i thought that calling inflate a second time will allow me to recover datas of my second particle that was created in my for loop but i can't retrieve it.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: one thing I am noticing is that you only allocate enough space in the decompress buffer `decomp` for one Particle. Change that to `2 * sizeof(Particle)` and tell me if there is still an error

Comment: also, how do you know there is no error? you do not check `response` for the value. If it is not `Z_OK` or `Z_STREAM_END` then there was an error

Comment: Hi @AK4749, thanx for your answer and correction. I just changed it and still get the same result.

Comment: @AK4749, I test these values on my computer, I just don't have write the statement on stackoverflow

Comment: ah ok. Well, if possible try to keep your SO code as close to your real code as possible so I can keep up with it. However, on another note, look at your creation of the two particles. Do you ever allocate new space for your second particle?

Comment: nvm, I see what you're doing

Comment: do you have a debugger? what does `decomp` look like?

Comment: Sorry for that. In fact I thought i could use the same var (p) for the two particles (I don't need them anymore after they have been compressed)

Comment: yep, you're correct, I didn't notice that at first

Comment: Actually I'm using g++ compiler and no debugger :S

Comment: haha ugh, I don't know how you're using ZLib without a debugger, it was a nightmare for me haha well in that case can you print its bytes out after it is created? I'm essentially trying to narrow down the location where the workflow fails. By seeing the anticipated results vs real results we can determine which step failed at which point we can correct the issue. So if you understand what I'm trying to do, you can probly do it faster than i with your own codebase

Comment: for example, printing `strm. 1) total_in 2) total_out` at each critical point will let you know if any stream operation did not consume the expected number of bytes

Comment: Well, I'm not sure i understand, but here is the result in bytes of the file i get after the for loop (compressed datas) :
0000000 78 9c 63 60 68 b0 67 60 70 70 60 00 12 0c 0c 07
0000010 1c 00 12 03 02 80

Is it what you mean ? thank for your time.

Comment: When I print spaceUsed after the loop I get 22

Comment: mmm not quite, as is quite obvious the compressed data means nothing to either of us. However, I was wondering if you could notice 1) during the deflates, are 24 bytes READ (spaceUsed shows how many are written). 2) during the inflate, are 24 bytes WRITTEN, and if so, what are they (if 24 are written, it is most likely accurate so i am assuming this is not the case.)

Comment: ah, didn't know total_in and total_out were vars of the z_stream object. In my for loop total_in is equals to 8 at first loop and 16 at second and last one, as if only 2 floats were deflate, is that it ?

Comment: There we go, that's exactly it. what does sizeof(Particle) return? it should return 12

Comment: First loop : total_in = 8, total_out = 2 Second loop : total_in = 16, total_out = 22

Comment: @AK4749, Yes, it gives me 12

Comment: AHA you are using sizeof(dataOriginal) in strm.avail_in, which is the size of the POINTER, not the buffer, which is (in 64bit) 8. SORRY that took so long god i apologize haha

Comment: @AK4749 First of all don't apologize :) Thx for your response but I don't know how to resolve the problem. Does I have to give strm.avail_in = sizeof(*dataOriginal); or strm.avail_in = sizeof(Particle) ?

Comment: sizeof(Particle), that will resolve at least the deflate issue haha hopefully the rest works as intended

Comment: as a sidenote, sizeof(*dataOriginal) would probably return 1, which is the size of 1 byte that you are pointing to

Comment: I still get the same problem after the correction :S

Comment: but now 24 bytes should be consumed, correct?

Comment: where you said first loop 8, second 16, it should now be 12 and 24.

Comment: now i'm getting at first loop : total_in = 12, total_out = 2
second loop : total_in = 24, total_out = 27

Comment: `strmInflate.avail_in = sizeof(Particle);` this line should be 27, the amount of compressed bytes, or `strmInflate.avail_in = spaceUsed;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strmInflate.avail_in = sizeof(Particle);` needs to be `strmInflate.avail_in = spaceUsed;`  You have to provide inflate all of the data produced by deflate.

At the end you want to get `Z_STREAM_END` from `inflate()`, not `Z_OK`.  Otherwise you have not decompressed the entire generated stream.

Note that per the documentation in [zlib.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h), you need to also set `next_in` and `avail_in` (to `Z_NULL` and `0` if you like) before calling `inflateInit()`

Depending on the size of the input and output buffers you will be using in the final application, you may need more loops to assure that `deflate()` and `inflate()` can finish their jobs.  Please see the [example of how to use zlib](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: Thanks Mark, i misunderstood the inflate utilisation